# WSO2 API Subscription Validation Failed with WSO2 IS as KM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have integrated the wso2is-6.1.0 as the key manager for wso2am-4.2.0 and I have deployed the PizzaShack API and subscribed it to the PizzaApp created in the devportal.
I have generated the client credentials using the wso2is key manager appearing in the devportal UI. However, when I generate a token using the same credentials and pass the same token in the header to invoke the API, I get the following error.

{"code":"900908","message":"Resource forbidden ","description":"User is NOT authorized to access the Resource. API Subscription validation failed."}

I followed the following documentations.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-wso2is-connector/

I have properly subscribed the API as well.
A solution to resolve this is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error code **900908** means the API is not subscribed by the application. Double-check whether the application from which you obtained the token is subscribed to the API you are invoking.

Make sure the **client_id** and **client_secret** you sent to get the token belong to the subscribed application." (If you are directly obtaining the token from the service provider, ensure that you are using the service provider created from the application you used to subscribe to the API.)

Comment: I have subscribed the API properly. I think the issue is that I followed two documentations for the same purpose one which describes the IS as the resident key manager and the other which describes IS as a third party key manager. I removed the IS as the third party KM config and the API works properly now using the credentials generated using the IS resident key manager. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You can use any of the options and it is depending on your use case. If you configure IS as a third part key manager, it decouples the OAuth client and access token management from the rest of its operations.